# iPhoneアプリのプログラミング言語を調べるにはどうしたらいいですか？

Tags: iphone

無料でダウンロードできるiPhoneアプリのプログラミング言語を調べたいときはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

基本的なことで申し訳ありません。

どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 自分で書くのではなく、配布されているアプリがどのような言語で書かれているかを調べたい…という事でしょうか。

Comment: はい！そうです。無料でiPhone上にダウンロードできるSNSアプリや通販アプリなど何の言語が書かれてるか調べたいです。

Comment: 他者のソフトウェアを解析することは、日本においては著作権法違反になる恐れがあります。そのアプリのライセンス契約がどうなっているかにも依るかもしれませんが、作成者がソースコードを公開していないと難しいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 違法なんですか？ありがとうございます。公開しているソースコードは何と調べればでてきますか？なかなか見つけられなくて、申し訳ありません。

Comment: 「特定の iPhone アプリがどのような言語で書かれているか調べる」ではなく、「iPhone アプリを作るにはどんな言語が使われているか」では駄目ですか？

Comment: それは分かるんですよ。ただ特定のいくつかのアプリは公開されてないんですね汗　ありがとうございました。オープンソースはアプリの名前と公開コードなどで調べたらでてきますかね？

Answer (score 0):

ほとんどのアプリは何らかのOSSを使用しています。そして、各アプリは不正を疑われないよう使用しているOSS名およびそのライセンスが記されています。

例えばTwitter for iPhoneであれば、

- Settings and Support

  - Settings and privacy

    - Addnitional resources

      - Legal notices

と辿ると、 [SFHFKeychainUtils](https://github.com/jayway/SFHFKeychainUtils) と ZipUtilities を使用しているようです。前者はObjective-C で書かれているので、Twitter for iPhoneもObjective-CかSwiftなんじゃないでしょうか。
Twitter程の規模になるとフレームワークを作成し提供する側になりますが、多くのアプリは一般に提供されているフレームワークを使用していることがほとんどであり、どのフレームワークを使用しているかはライセンスの記述から判断できます。

Comment: 遅くなってしまい、すみません。OSS名を調べ、ライセンスの記述から推測するんですね！ありがとうございます。とてもためになりました。